# How can I fill vector with values in the most efficient way in cpp?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

Hi I have a function that assigns values from 0 to the size of ELEMENT_COUNT
How can I improve the performance of this function?

```
constexpr size_t ELEMENT_COUNT = 1000 * 10000;

std::vector<uint64_t> fill_vector(size_t elementCount) {
    std::vector<uint64_t> vec(elementCount);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    return vec;
}
```

I thought about using basic assigment instead of using push_back(i):

```
std::vector<uint64_t> fill_vector(size_t elementCount) {

    std::vector<uint64_t> vec(elementCount);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
        vec[i] = i;
    }
    return vec;
}
```

but does anyone have an idea for a better improvement?

Comment: For that example, use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead of your own loop.

Comment: [Resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)  or [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) would be helpful before adding items

Comment: Forget about efficiency, how about fixing major breakage? The first `fill_vector` appears to return a vector that's going to be twice as big as you think it is.

Comment: The most efficient is to calculate at compile-time. Is that an option?

Comment: Given element count is nowhere near 2^64 how about using a 32 bit type or even smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently doing can be done in a simpler way and it is usually fast enough:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

auto fill_vector(std::uint64_t elementCount) {
    std::vector<std::uint64_t> vec(elementCount);

    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::uint64_t{});
    return vec;
}
```

Here's another solution, not sure if it is faster, but worth trying out. It should avoid the zero-initialization and the bounds-checks:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

template <class T = int>
struct IntIter {
    T i;
    const auto& operator*() const { return i; }
    auto operator==(IntIter rhs) const { return i == rhs.i; }
    auto operator!=(IntIter rhs) const { return !operator==(rhs); }
    auto& operator++() {
        ++i;
        return *this;
    }
    auto operator-(IntIter rhs) const {
        return static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(i - rhs.i);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct std::iterator_traits<IntIter<T>> {
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = const T;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
};

auto fill_vector(std::uint64_t elementCount) {
    return std::vector<std::uint64_t>(IntIter<std::uint64_t>{0},
                                      IntIter<std::uint64_t>{elementCount});
}
```

Comment: `iota` isnt faster than a hand written loop, or do I miss something? I mean it is not slower than a handwritten loop would be, which is already a really cool thing.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I meant to firstly show a nicer way of what OP did and then show a potentially faster way.

Comment: thats fine, I'd just be careful to present a standard algorithm when OP asks for "most efficient" because they might expect it to be super more efficient than their loop, then one day learn that it isnt and then be dissappointed for the wrong reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your first example is incorrect. This version of vector constructor makes a vector, reserves a memory for `elementCount` elements and initializes them with default values, in this case with zeros. Then you are adding additional `elementCount` elements that are `0..elementCount`.

In the second example you reserved a memeory, initizlized it with zeros and changed zeroes to values you need.

What you essentially want is to reserve a memory and fill elements without default initialization of them with push_back/emplace_back (with trivial types such as uint there wouldn't be difference)

So, the right and simple way to do this would be something like this:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> fill_vector(size_t elementCount) {

    std::vector<uint64_t> vec;
    vec.reserve(elementCount);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    return vec;
}
```